# ¿Cómo ubicar en una matriz una coordenada recibida en pixeles?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy hace tiempo trabado con un trabajo de mi universidad. Éste consiste en desarrollar un 5 en línea con gamelib. Mi problema radica en que no estoy logrando ubicar la ficha en la posición correcta de mi matriz `grilla` las coordenadas en pixeles que recibo en mi función juego_actualizar.
Adjunto el código que creo que puede ser útil:

Éstas son las constantes

```
#Fichas
FICHA_X = 'X'
FICHA_O = 'O'
VACIO = ""

#Celdas
ANCHO_JUEGO = 10
ALTO_JUEGO = 10
```

La función donde creo la matriz

```
def crear_grilla_vacia():
"""Devuelve una grilla con ANCHO_JUEGO x ALTO_JUEGO celdas vacías."""

grilla = []
for y in range(ALTO_JUEGO):
    fila = []
    for x in range(ANCHO_JUEGO):
        fila.append(VACIO)
    grilla.append(fila)
return grilla
```

Y esta es la función donde tengo mi problema. (La ventana tiene un tamaño de 500x500 px y la grilla es de 400 ancho x 300 alto)

```
def juego_actualizar(juego, x, y):
"""Actualizar el estado del juego

x e y son las coordenadas (en pixels) donde el usuario hizo click.
Esta función determina si esas coordenadas corresponden a una celda
del tablero; en ese caso determina el nuevo estado del juego y lo
devuelve."""

grilla, turno_jugadorO = juego

#Ubicar ficha y cambiar turno si y sólo si no está terminado y click dentro de una celda vacia 
if not terminado(juego) and (50 <= x < 450 and 100 <= y < 400): 
    fila = y // 30
    columna = x // 40  
    if turno_jugadorO:
        grilla[fila][columna] = FICHA_O
    else:
        grilla[fila][columna] = FICHA_X
return grilla, not turno_jugadorO
```

[image: Por ultimo cómo se ve la ventana]

Nota: en mi país grilla significa cuadrícula

Comment: ¿No debería ser `fila = (y - 100) // 30`? Misma cosa con `columna`

Comment: @CandidMoe lo pobré de esa manera pero al debuggear veo que la ficha se ubica en una posicion incorrecta, ej: al clickear en la celda 0,0 la ficha se ubica en 9,0 ya que `columna` en ese caso vale -1

Comment: @TomásIglesias probaste con `fila = (y - 100) // 30` y `columna = (x - 50) // 40` (o sea, restandole la abcisa y la ordenada de la posición donde empieza la grilla, a la posición en la que clickea?), ahí no podría dar una fila o columna negativa porque tambien compruebas que la posición este dentro de la grilla (`(50 <= x < 450 and 100 <= y < 400)`)

Comment: @braver Solucionado! Al restar la abcisa y la ordenada se ubican donde deberían. Muchas gracias!